# Unable to get multiple charts to overlap

Tags: tableau-api

So here is a quick contrived example that is directly analogous to the challenge I have.
Suppose that I am looking to plot out order quantity for different users, based on what order number that is (order number here in the chronological sense, not order number as a unique identifier).

So suppose I have two users placing orders as outlined below.

| OrderNumber | OrderBy | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 4 |
| 2 | Alice | 3 |
| 3 | Alice | 6 |
| 1 | Bob | 5 |
| 2 | Bob | 7 |
| 3 | Bob | 2 |
| 4 | Bob | 1 |
| 5 | Bob | 8 |

So to plot both with OrderNumber on the x-axis and Quantity on the y-axis, I put OrderNumber on my column shelf, OrderBy on my row shelf, and sum(quantity) on my row shelf.

This gives me what I want in two separate graphs, but the problem is that I am not able to combine the two graphs. I click on the green triangle that appears over the lower graph's y-axis, and attempt to drag it to the upper graph's y-axis, and I get the two vertical green likes where it looks like they will be combined but then they do not combine.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your goal is other than just in one graph but you can put order by on the columns and get this:

[image]

Or move Order by in front of Order number.

[image]